# Determining using ALSA API whether device is default

Tags: c, linux, alsa

I looking for example to determining using ALSA API whether device is default or not.

Check is for string in this form:

```
const *char device = "hw:1,0"
```

I want to create a function, using ALSA API, witch return 1 if is set as "default" ALSA device or 0 if not

```
static int alsa_is_default_device (const *char device)
{
    /* ALSA API */
}
```

maybe using

```
snd_config_search( snd_config, "defaults.ctl.card", &config )
```

Any help is welcome

I uses custom alsa module for control audio devices:

```
err = snd_pcm_open(&handle, device, SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK, 0);
```

I tried to pass 'hw:0,0' for 'device' into this function and return error:

```
Failed to set a supported rate. Operation not permitted.
```

if I pass 'default' for device it work.

I need to use 'hw:x,x' form for device(s) that is not set as ALSA DEFAULT DEVICE (e.g. hw:1,0) and 'default' for ALSA DEFAULT DEVICE, because most of the default devices (plughw, default, etc.) support automatic conversions, and thus accept all formats. hw devices do not. I need for same sound device to negotiated sample rate conversion,

Example with aplay -L output:

```
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
sysdefault:CARD=ICH5
    Intel ICH5, Intel ICH5
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=ICH5,DEV=0
    Intel ICH5, Intel ICH5
    Front speakers
surround40:CARD=ICH5,DEV=0
    Intel ICH5, Intel ICH5
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=ICH5,DEV=0
    Intel ICH5, Intel ICH5
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=ICH5,DEV=0
    Intel ICH5, Intel ICH5
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=ICH5,DEV=0
    Intel ICH5, Intel ICH5
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
iec958:CARD=ICH5,DEV=0
    Intel ICH5, Intel ICH5 - IEC958
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
dmix:CARD=ICH5,DEV=0
    Intel ICH5, Intel ICH5
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=ICH5,DEV=4
    Intel ICH5, Intel ICH5 - IEC958
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=ICH5,DEV=0
    Intel ICH5, Intel ICH5
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=ICH5,DEV=4
    Intel ICH5, Intel ICH5 - IEC958
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=ICH5,DEV=0
    Intel ICH5, Intel ICH5
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=ICH5,DEV=4
    Intel ICH5, Intel ICH5 - IEC958
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=ICH5,DEV=0
    Intel ICH5, Intel ICH5
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=ICH5,DEV=4
    Intel ICH5, Intel ICH5 - IEC958
    Hardware device with all software conversions
```

Comment: What do you mean with "default"?

Comment: alsa setting "default" versus "hw:0,0"

Comment: To get automatic sample rate conversion, if needed, use `plughw` instead of `hw`.